# Is it better to layout subviews in layout/layoutSubviews method?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

This question is for both `cocoa` and `cocoa touch`. But I'll write an example just for `cocoa`.

As I understood, I can `setNeedsLayout` to `YES` multiple times in a cycle and `-layout` will be called just once. But are there any other benefits of laying out subviews in `-layout` method?

Explanation / example: At the moment I'm laying out my subviews in custom `viewController` (that has default `NSView`) every time I call custom `redraw` method. And I call `redraw` method only when user changes some properties so I really want to relayout subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of external circumstances not under your direct control that might cause the system to want to lay out your views. For example, device rotation or incoming calls on iOS, or window resizing on OS X. If you have your layout logic in the standard places, then your code accommodates these without any additional effort, and in the places your internal state changes, you can request such a layout explicitly.

To turn your question around: is there a significant benefit to *not* doing your layout in the standard way? Do you believe that this will be a performance issue? Have you measured it to see whether it is *actually* a performance issue?